# functions inside a class

Tags: javascript, html

We need to make a class called `Series` with two methods

1. `triNums` - function that returns you a triangular series by the number it recives eg: if the function gets 5 - 1, 3, 6, 10, 15
2. `fibNums` - function that returns you a fibonacci sequence by the number it 
   recives eg: if the function gets 5 - 0,1,1,2,3,5

Each of the functions need to be executed when pressing on a button (`fibo`)(`tri`) and each element of the result should be displayed on a button

```js
class Series {
  tri() {
    const num = document.querySelector("#num").value
    if (num) {
      addBtns(triNums(num));
    }
  }

  addBtns(arr) {
    const feed = document.querySelector("#feed");
    var btns = ""; //no buttons by default
    for (let v of arr) { //iterate over all values
      btns += "<button>" + v + "</button>";
    }
    feed.innerHTML = btns;
  }
  triNums(num) {
    var triNums = [];
    for (let n = 0; n < num.value; n++) {
      triNums[n] = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    }
    return triNums;
  }
  triNum(n) {
      return (n * (n + 1) / 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="home6617.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Enter Name <input id="name" placeholder="Enter name"></input>
  <button onclick="sayHello()">Click me</button>
  <h1 id="hello"></h1>
  <input id="num"></input>
  <button onclick="tri()">triangular</button>
  <div id="feed"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what languages you are supposed to use?

Comment: javascript & html

Comment: read about classes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: And what do you need help with?  Be *specific*

Comment: first of all,sorry that I'm not specific enough.When I press the "triangular" button after writing a number inside the input i get the error:tri is not defined

Comment: That's because it's in a class, so you need to call it through a `Series` object.

Comment: You're missing a bunch of closing braces at the end of the code.

Comment: So it needs to be something like `var s = new Series; s.tri();`

Comment: Somebody edited the post and deleted @Assaf 's closing braces for some reason

Comment: Apologies, I have re-edited to include the closing braces back in

Comment: @Sandman please be careful when editing questions. Now its not working, and your edit needs to be approved :/

Comment: @Jonasw Understood.. I think it has since been approved :)

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes:

1. you pass #num.value to triNums, which is a Number, and then you try to access its value, which is unneccessary and impossible.
2. You cannot call tri() as it is part of a Series instance. You could do *(new Series).tri()* .
3. Same applies for inner function calls, you must access them via *this* :

```js
class Series {
  tri() {
    const num = document.querySelector("#num").value
    if (num) {
      this.addBtns(this.triNums(num));
    }
  }

  addBtns(arr) {
    const feed = document.querySelector("#feed");
    var btns = ""; //no buttons by default
    for (let v of arr) { //iterate over all values
      btns += "<button>" + v + "</button>";
    }
    feed.innerHTML = btns;
  }
  triNums(num) {
    var triNums = [];
    for (let n = 0; n < num; n++) {
      triNums[n] = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    }
    return triNums;
  }
  triNum(n) {
      return (n * (n + 1) / 2);
  }
} 

function start(){
 (new Series).tri();   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="home6617.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="feed"></div>
 <input id="num" />
 <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
</body>

</html>
```